# Cannot Set Data to RecyclerView via Retrofit in Android

Tags: android, json, retrofit, android-cardview

I can normally get and show data on Toast message, but I cannot add them to RecyclerView. How can I do this? Please help me. Thanks. I am sharing my code below.

> NewsCatalog.java

```
public class NewsCatalog {
public List<MainNodes> nodes;
```

}

> MainNodes.java

```
public class MainNodes {
public SubNodes node;
```

}

> SubNodes.java

```
public class SubNodes {
public String body;

public String getBody() {
    return body;
}

public void setBody(String body) {
    this.body = body;
}
```

}

> NewsInterface

```
public interface NewsService {
String BASE_URL = "http://test.muhabirce.de/app/term/";

@GET("saglik")
Call<NewsCatalog> newsCatalog();
```

}

> Adapter.java

```
public class NewsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NewsAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private ArrayList<SubNodes> subNodes;
private Context context;

public NewsAdapter(ArrayList<SubNodes> subNodes, Context context) {
    this.subNodes = subNodes;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public NewsAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context)
            .inflate(R.layout.card_view_items, parent, false);

    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(NewsAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.tvText.setText(subNodes.get(position).getBody());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return subNodes.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private TextView tvText;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        tvText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvText);
    }
}
```

}

> MainActivity.java

```
private void bindDatas() {

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(NewsService.BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    NewsService newsService = retrofit.create(NewsService.class);
    Call<NewsCatalog> requestCatalog = newsService.newsCatalog();


    requestCatalog.enqueue(new Callback<NewsCatalog>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<NewsCatalog> call, Response<NewsCatalog> response) {
            SubNodes subNodess = new SubNodes();
            if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                Log.i("TAG", "Error: " + response.code());
            } else {
                NewsCatalog catalog = response.body();
                try {
                    for (MainNodes m : catalog.nodes
                            ) {
                        subNodess.setBody(m.node.body);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "" + e.getMessage());
                }
            }

            subNodes.add(subNodess);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<NewsCatalog> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + t.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: Are you calling 'execute' anywhere on your requestCatalog?

Comment: No, Should I call it on bindData() method? @IvanWooll

Comment: Apologies, I misunderstood how Retrofit2 works. requestCatalog.enqueue should execute the call. What debugging have you done to compare the response you get back from the server to what you are expecting?

Answer (score 0):

You should not create a new Subnodes object in response callback. Adapter does not have reference to this object and so the changes in data is not reflected. Update the subnodes object in the recyclerview adapter. Then only notifyDataSetChanged() will reflect the change in data.

Comment: Why? Didn't you understand my answer or have I got your question wrong?

Comment: No, I am just new to this topic and I am a bit confused. However I will try. Thanks @user3215142